# How to filter model by the sum of an attribute of its has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a model named `Promoter` and a model named `PromoterProject`. Each promoter has many promoter projects:

```
class Promoter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promoter_projects
end

class PromoterProject < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :promoter
end
```

The `PromoterProject` model has a column `work_days` of type integer. It represents the amount of days the promoter has worked on the project.

I need to implement a filter that *returns the promoters with total work days (across all of their projects) between the specified values*. I am having difficulties building the query using the active record query methods. So far I have the following:

```
Promoter.includes(:promoter_projects).group('promoters.id').select('promoters.*, sum(promoter_projects.work_days) as total_days').where('total_days between ? and ?', min_value, max_value)
```

I get an error saying that *the `total_days` column cannot be found*.

Most of the line (the group and the select statements) I have stitched from things I found in the interned, so I am not fully understanding what exactly is happening. If you can provide me with additional explanations I will really appreciate it!

Additional Info:

Rails version 4.1.4
PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Albin said, use joins. However, when using aggregate functions, it is simplest to use `having`:

```
Promoter.joins(:promoter_projects)
.having('SUM("promoter_projects"."work_days") BETWEEN ? AND ?', min_value, max_value)
.group("promoters.id")
```

Comment: Yes! Meanwhile I also managed to come to this solution. The `having` clause allows the usage of aggregated functions inside of it, whereas the `where` clause does not. Also the select statement in my chain messed with the `count` that was being called by the paging. After removing it I found out about the `having` clause.

Comment: Good to hear that you figured it out! You can think of `having` as `where` for the aggregate functions. It is in line with how raw SQL works, so might be worth checking up on that. :-)